# simple output of xml from python

Tags: python, xml

I need to output XML from python in a very minimalist way:

- I can't use any external libraries beyond what's already in Python 2.6.5
- I need to output XML tags, and text contents, with no attributes

At this point I'm using print statements to explicitly print out angle-bracket tags, and the only thing really stopping me is escaping text within a tag, which I do not know how to do.

Any suggestions?

---

**update:** Is there anything like Java's [StAX XMLStreamWriter](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1287) for Python? I may have a large XML document to produce, and I don't need (or want) to hold the entire document in memory.

**update #2:** I also need to escape random unicode or non-ASCII characters in the text besides `<`, `>` and `&`.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to escape "random" unicode or non-ASCII characters? Can't you just encode it in UTF-8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it looks like SAX isn't that hard to use after all. Here's an example.

xmltest.py:

```
import xml.sax.xmlreader
import xml.sax.saxutils

def testJunk(file, e2content):
  attr0 = xml.sax.xmlreader.AttributesImpl({})
  x =  xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator(file)
  x.startDocument()
  x.startElement("document", attr0)

  x.startElement("element1", attr0)
  x.characters("bingo")
  x.endElement("element1")

  x.startElement("element2", attr0)
  x.characters(e2content)
  x.endElement("element2")

  x.endElement("document")
  x.endDocument()
```

tested:

```
>>> import xmltest
>>> xmltest.testJunk(open("test.xml","w"), "wham < 3!")
```

produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<document><element1>bingo</element1><element2>wham &lt; 3!</element2></document>
```

Comment: You need to use `x =  xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator(file, "UTF-8")` **and** you need to feed it `unicode` objects (or `str` objects that contain only ASCII) in a considered non-random fashion. If you have text in some legacy encoding e.g. cp1252, then decode it before stuffing it into `x.characters()`

Comment: Also for portability you should use "wb" in your file open() call.

Answer (score 2):

If task is as simple, [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) may suffice. Here goes short example:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Document

# create xml document
document = Document()

# create root element
root = document.createElement("root")
document.appendChild(root)

# create child element
child = document.createElement("child")
child.setAttribute("tag", "test")
root.appendChild(child)

# insert some text
atext = document.createTextNode("Foo bar")
child.appendChild(atext)

# print created xml
print(document.toprettyxml(indent="    "))
```

Comment: +1 for the quick example. I can't use it for my particular application, as I have a potentially large XML file to produce + don't need to hold/manipulate a DOM-style XML object in memory.

Answer (score 2):

[ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) comes with Python 2.6:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element('root')
sub = ET.SubElement(root,'sub')
sub.text = 'Hello & Goodbye'
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('out.xml')
# OR
ET.dump(root)
```

#### Output

```
<root><sub>Hello &amp; Goodbye</sub></root>
```

Answer (score 1):

[xml.sax.saxutils.escape(data[, entities])](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.utils.html).

Comment: That only escapes `<`, `>`, `&` plus specific entities. If I have any random unicode or ASCII characters, I need to escape them too.